# What is? $ \lim_{x \to \infty} \left(\frac{e}{\left( 1 + \frac {1}{x} \right)^x} \right)^x $

Tags: calculus

> Find $$ \lim_{x \to \infty} \left( \dfrac{e}{\left( \left( 1 + \frac {1}{x} \right)^x \right)} \right)^x. $$

---

$ \lim_{x \to \infty} \left( \dfrac{e}{\left( \left( 1 + \frac {1}{x} \right)^x \right)} \right)^x = \lim_{x \to \infty} \left( \dfrac {e}{e} \right)^x = \lim_{x \to \infty} 1^x = \infty $

Why is this incorrect?

Comment: $1^{x}=1$ for all $x$.

Comment: Your error is e/e = x. Instead, the answer is e^x/1^x = e^x.

Comment: $ 1^x \ne \infty $

Comment: (n.b.: a previous edit changed the problem into an incorrect form.  I've fixed a couple of typos to make the question more properly interesting again.)

Comment: jujuju: I've fixed the previous mistaken edit, but I strongly encourage you to leave the question in TeXified form - it is _much_ more readable this way.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki, you just added a pair of unnecessary parenthesis to my revision?

Comment: @ChristophPegel Actually, I never even saw your revision, mea culpa!  I saw Ahaan Rungta's TeXification (which inadvertently changed the meaning of the question) and worked on top of that one, but didn't see your version; I suspect our edits crossed paths in revision.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki thx for your help,but i dont know how to use TeXified form

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take the logarithm,

$$\begin{align}
\log \left(\frac{e}{\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x}\right)^x &= x\log \frac{e}{\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x}\\
&= x\left(1 - x \log \left(1+\frac1x\right)\right)\\
&= x\left(1 - x\left(\frac1x - \frac{1}{2x^2} + O(x^{-3})\right) \right)\\
&= x\left(1 - 1 + \frac{1}{2x} + O(x^{-2})\right)\\
&= \frac12 + O(x^{-1}).
\end{align}$$

And hence

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \left(\frac{e}{\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x}\right)^x = e^{1/2}.$$

Comment: log=>ln? why ln(1+x^(-1))=1/x-1/(2x^2)+o(x^-3)

Comment: I still dont know Why is this incorrect?

Comment: @jujuju $\log$ is indeed the natural logarithm (mathematicians rarely use $\ln$). The Taylor expansion of $\log (1+y)$ is $$\log (1+y) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}y^n,$$ cutting off after the quadratic term gives the used form (with $y = 1/x$). Your result was incorrect because you can't separate the limit into two steps here where the exponent doesn't have a finite limit (and of course $1^x = 1$ for all $x$). When you have $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} f(x)^{g(x)}$, you can separate the limits if both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ have a finite limit, but not if $g(x) = x$.